# Phonegap Build iOS: app tries to install on every click on the app icon on the device, but fail without message

Tags: ios, cordova, adobe, ipa, failed-installation

i try to use the Phonegap Build Service from Adobe, but i can't install the *.ipa (iOS) result from the compilation on my iOS-Device. I try to use it with Dreamweaver CC and the build in upload. I have upload my distribution *.p12 and *.mobileprovision file to the Adobe Phonegap Build server, so this works.

After creation of the app I could transfer the app from iTunes or the barcode link to my device.
After the transfer the app (try to) installs, but the app icon stays grey and the app doesn't start.
Every time I click on the app icon on the device, the app try to install itself, but the app icon stays grey and the app doesn't start.

Could anyone suggest a solution.

Devices: iPhone 5s, iPad 3 with iOS 7
Phonegap Build Version: 2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault was that I use the development provisioning file.

You have to use your distribution provisioning profile (*.mobileprovision) and your iphone distribution profile (*.p12).

I you only develop for yourself, you have to create a distribution provisioning profile on the Apple development portal under "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
You need only create an adhoc profile with the devices you want to use.